# SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT member_id ) AS active FROM amember_payments WHERE com

Tags: sql, performance, lag, amember

So my database has a few hundred thousand members and the processing software was clearly not meant for a database this size.  So im having some significant lag issues.  I was curious if anyone had a trick for this annoying query.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) AS active
           FROM amember_payments
           WHERE completed > 0 AND expire_date >= '2012-08-01' AND amount > 0
```

It scans the entire database.

Comment: What RBDMS is this for? Also, what indexes does the `amember_payments` table have?

Comment: Have you indexed the columns in your query?

Comment: -1 For asking about performance while concealing the database system in use. This is just disrespecting the time of people trying to help. The answer directly depends on the RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to add an index.  Without knowing your data distribution I cannot tell you which column(s) to add it on for sure but my hunch would suggest 'expire_date' is the best place.  Your index should be on the most distinct field to allow sql server to quickly remove rows from consideration without the table scans.

Answer (score 2):

If it scans, you need indexes. From your query, it looks like you should add an index for completed, expire_date, and amount columns. But without knowing the data better, I don't know the exact order I would use.

Comment: I would recommend limiting your indexes to the fewest columns that produce the desired results.  The more specific your indexes the less likely sql server will choose to use the index for a query.  If you add three columns to an index it will only be used if all three columns exist within the query.

Comment: But, given a performance problem, a single index covering the query criteria should yield the best results. And I don't believe your statement is true. If I did a query and my criteria were the first two columns in an index covering three columns, there is no reason I know of why that index would be less optimal than another only covering the two columns.

Comment: Best results are relative.  People tend to kill themselves with too many specific indexes to achieve a few extra crumbs of performance.   A specific index will yield the best results on the first execution of this exact query, however a more general index is more likely to be kept in memory for use with queries across the board granting greater performance improvements overall.

Comment: Fair enough. But for me, unless this query is an outlier, I would make a single index.